# How will the basis vectors of the subspace $\mathbb{R}^n$ consisting of those vectors $A=(a_1,\cdots,a_n)$ such that $a_1+\cdots+a_n=0$ look like?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

How will the basis vectors of the subspace $\mathbb{R}^n$ consisting of those vectors $A=(a_1,\cdots,a_n)$ such that $a_1+\cdots+a_n=0$ look like?

The initial problem was "what is the dimension of the subspace $\mathbb{R}^n$ consisting of those vectors $A=(a_1,\cdots,a_n)$ such that $a_1+\cdots+a_n=0$ ?

I solved this question using the liner mapping $L:\mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ s.t. $L_{I}(X)=I.X$, where $I=(1,\cdots,1); X=(x_1,\cdots,x_n)$. It is being asked that what is the $dimension[kernel(L)]$ which is equal to $n-1$.

Now, I wanted to solved this question not using the $dim[V]=dim[Im(F)]+dim[Ker(F)]$ but looking at the subspace itself. How will the basis vector of the subspace asked in the question will be?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $e_i$ denote the $i$th coordinate vector in $\mathbb{R}^n$. I claim that a basis for this space is given by 
$$
e_1 - e_n, e_2 - e_n, \dots, e_{n-1} - e_n.
$$
It remains for you to prove that this is a linearly independent set which spans your space. If you're willing to use the fact that this space has dimension $n-1$, then you only need to prove one of these.

Answer (score 0):

To prove that they are Linearly Independent, all we have to do is P.T. if 
$$
x_1v_1+\cdots+x_{n-1}v_{n-1}=0\\
\Rightarrow x_1e_1-x_1e_n+x_2e_2-x_2e_n+\cdots+x_{n-1}e_{n-1}-x_{n-1}e_{n}=0\\
\Rightarrow x_1e_1+x_2e_2+\cdots+x_{n-1}e_{n-1}-(x_1e_n+x_2e_n+\cdots+x_{n-1}e_{n})=0 \\
\Rightarrow x_1=\cdots=x_{n-1}=0
$$

where $v_1=e_1-e_n,\cdots,v_{n-1}=e_{n-1}-e_n $

All we need to show now is that any element of the subspace can be expressed in terms of the basis of the subspace i.e.

$v=a_1v_1+\cdots+a_{n-1}v_{n-1}=(a_1,a_2,\cdots,a_{n-1},-(a_1+a_2+\cdots+a_{n-1}))$

which means that $a_1+a_2+\cdots+a_{n}=0$